# Motor rewinding - saturation concerns

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, saturation

After reading a lot about 3 phase BLDC motors there's one concern that's nowhere to be found.

Let's say that we have a 1000 K<sub>v</sub> motor and we want to rewind it to 10 K<sub>v</sub> to get unrealistically high torque at low RPM. And let's say that we have the right diameter replacement copper wire.

Will there be saturation from iron or permanent magnets?

This questions is probably very wrong as magnets are passive and will probably not saturate, but I'm really unsure and don't have sufficient knowledge about magnetism, so from my perspective only the iron laminations can saturate from high enough force produced from current circulating around them.

Comment: The gap comes to the rescue mainly. It's "Kv" BTW

Comment: Rewinding it will only change the voltage (and current) at which it achieves its rated performance : the achievable performance itself is essentially unchanged. It may be more convenient to supply 10A at 100V than 1000A at  1V : that's why you rewind.

Comment: That's the main reason for doing this. Better shove 5A instead of  > 30A . Interesting point about air gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be saturation from iron or permanent magnets?

No.

Magnetic flux is directly proportional to current multiplied by turns. Assuming all the winding space is used, if you increase the number of turns then you have to decrease the wire diameter, which increases resistance and reduces current draw. The result will be *less* flux and torque than the original motor could produce on the same voltage.

For example if you double the number of turns then each turn has to fit in half the area, so its resistance will be double that of the original. Since you have doubled the number of turns, the total winding resistance will increase by 4 times and the current will be reduced to 1/4. The result is half the flux (and torque) of the original motor.

But what if you raise the voltage? Double the voltage and current is doubled to half that of the original winding, and flux and torque are restored. Kv was halved by having twice as many turns, but the higher voltage makes up for it. Power dissipated in the windings is also the same, so you get back to the same performance as the original motor but at double the voltage and half the current.

To get *more* torque you have to go the other way and *reduce* the number of turns, which increases current. Go too far and the flux produced may be enough to saturate the core, then any further current increase has less effect. Theoretically the flux could get high enough to demagnetize the magnets, but the current required to demagnetize Neodym magnets would probably melt the windings.

The real danger is heat from the windings raising magnet temperature enough to  demagnetize them. This is not just theoretical, as high power magnets may suffer partial demagnetization at temperatures as low as 80 °C.

Comment: What an answer! Whole point of my question was to ask if a motor can be rewound to get more torque with less current with same voltage supply. Since current is limited when using FOC as the most common method of control and speed is not a concern. If I understood correctly, this calculations should hold true when motor is Not Rotating:
Motor has 10 turns and 1 Ohm resistance and needs 20 Amps to get 1 Nm of torque with power dissipated in the windings at 400 Watts. Rewinding this to 40 turns would get us 16 Ohm and 5 A at 400W.

Comment: So rewinding can basically remove strain from mosfets and shunts from an inverter. If it's okay to have less speed. It's interesting that this works in the same way as gear reduction, except that it doesn't when motor is not moving.

Comment: If you don't need the speed (and torque) that your voltage provides then rewinding with more turns makes better use of the voltage and reduces strain on the controller because it can use higher PWM ratio with lower motor current. So you are matching the motor to the supply voltage. Gimbal motors are an extreme example, they have many turns producing high resistance which allows operation at zero rpm, but are very weak due to the low current draw.

Comment: _"Motor has 10 turns and 1 Ohm resistance and needs 20 Amps to get 1 Nm of torque with power dissipated in the windings at 400 Watts. Rewinding this to 40 turns would get us 16 Ohm and 5 A at 400W"_.  And 20A x 1 ohm = 20V, 5A x 16 ohms = 80V. So same torque, same power, but different voltage and current. But 20V / 16 ohms = 1.25A, so 4 times less (maximum) torque at the same voltage.

Comment: Now it's crystal clear what is meant by "To get more torque you have to go the other way and reduce the number of turns, which increases current." By this you meant that theoretical torque peak on a fixed voltage supply increases with less turns and lower resistance, if heat can be effectively dissipated. This was a great explanation, got way more than I asked for but every piece of info is superb!